# Solving an overdetermined system of linear equations with least square roots (not squares)

Tags: least-squares, point-cloud

An overdetermined system of linear equations can be solved by approximation as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system.
I also need to solve such a system $P_{act} = T * P_{nom}$, where the transformation matrix $T$ between nominal 2D positions $P_{nom}$ and actual 2D positions $P_{act}$ of a point cloud is searched.
The transformation matrix is 2x2, and the number of points is 3 or more.

The currently implemented calculation method uses the pseudo-inverse, which works well, if the goal is getting equally low errors on each point. As the related [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) says,

> A common use of the pseudoinverse is to compute a "best fit" (least squares) solution to a system of linear equations that lacks a solution ...

Now, I have a different goal when calculating the transformation matrix: The orientation of a grid of dots is searched. Outliers in this grid should be weightes less. Therefore, the goal is not reducing large errors anymore (*least squares*), but reducing small errors at the cost of increasing large errors, a *least square roots* method, so to speak.
When I search for that term, I only found
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34237/least-square-root-fitting-a-fitting-method-with-multiple-minima
but I don't see how this could help.

How can I calculate a transformation matrix between the nominal and actual positions of a point cloud, using a least square roots method?